# Simple Random Walk: Hitting time of 1 is a.s. finite

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk, stopping-times, independence

Let $X_i, i \geq 0$ be i.i.d. random variables with $P[X_i=1]=P[X_i=-1]=1/2$ and consider $S_n = X_1 + \dotsc + X_n$ for $n \geq 1$, $S_0=0$, the symmetric simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $T_1:=\inf{\{n \geq 0 \,\colon \, S_n = 1\}}$ be the hitting time of $1$.

How can one see that $T_1 < \infty$ a.s.?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate $P(T_1=n)$ (for odd $n$)?

Comment: By reflection principle, $P(T\le n)=P(S_n\ge 1)+P(S_n\ge 2)=1-P(S_n=0,1)\to 1$. From CLT we get $P(T>n)=P(S_n=0,1)\sim \frac 2{\sqrt {2\pi n}}$ which yields $E(T)=\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. Is there some easier approach not relying on CLT or very specific knowledge about Catalan numbers? Is there maybe an approach using Borel-Cantelli?

Comment: Reflection principle suffices as you don't need CLT/Catalan numbers to see that $P(S_n\in\{0,1\})\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I was not careful enough in reading your comment and thought one would use CLT (we have seen another proof for $E[T]= \infty$ using Wald's identity). Can you explain a littl ebit more how you get these equalities? So $\{T \leq n\}$ implies that up to time $n$ we hit $1$, which means that $S_m = 1$ for some $m \leq n$. I do not see how the reflection principle applies here. Also, I do not see the second equality. Isn't $P[S_n \geq 1] + P[S_n \geq 2]= P[S_n=1] + 2 P[S_n \geq 2]$? Then how do you argue that $P[S_n \in \{0,1\}] \rightarrow 0$?

Comment: 1. Since this is *the* application of the reflection principle, I wonder as to where you've seen it used. 2. $P(S_n\ge 1)=P(S_n\le -1)$. 3. Informally, distribution of $S_n$ flattens more and more it's support grows linearly - so occupation probability of each site goes to zero. Formally, you express $P(S_n=0,1)$ through a binomial coefficient and apply Stirling's approximation.

Answer (score 7):

In this case, we can give an easy estimate on the tail probability of $T_1$. Notice that

$$ \{T_1 = 2n+1\} = \{S_1 \leq 0, \cdots, S_{2n-1} \leq 0, S_{2n} = 0, S_{2n+1} = 1\}. $$

Using [one of the equivalent characterization of Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics), we can explicitly compute the probability of this event as

$$ \Bbb{P}(T_1 = 2n+1) = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}C_n = \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}(n+1)} \binom{2n}{n}. $$

From this, we explicitly compute the probability generating function of $T_1$ by

$$ |z| < 1 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathbb{E}[z^{T_1}] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n \mathbb{P}(T_1 = n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{C_n}{2^{2n+1}} z^{2n+1} = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z}. $$

Letting $z \to 1^-$ shows that, by the monotone convergence theorem,

$$ \mathbb{P}(T_1 < \infty) = \lim_{z \to 1^-} \mathbb{E}[z^{T_1}] = \lim_{z \to 1^-} \frac{1-\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z} = 1. $$

Therefore $\Bbb{P}(T_1 = \infty) = 0$.

---

**Addendum.** Using this, we can also show that

$$ \mathbb{E}[T_1 z^{T_1}] = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-z^2}}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}}, $$

and so, $T_1$ infinite expectation $\Bbb{E}[T_1] = \infty$.

Comment: $\Bbb{P}(T_1 > 2n) = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}(T_1 = 2k+1)$ is it true? It seems you have missed a lot of terms.

Comment: @Dingo13, It does not misses a lot of terms, but you are right in that I am missing a term. More precisely, the alleged equality is actually missing the single term $\mathbb{P}(T = \infty)$, which is crucial for the argument. I will fix it later.

Comment: I think you missed the even terms, i.e. $T_1=2k+2$, ... Otherwise I do not understand the answer.

Comment: @Dingo13, Notice that $S_{2n}$ takes only even integers and $S_{2n+1}$ takes only odd integers. Since $T_1$ is the hitting time for the value $1$, $T_1$ can take only odd-integer values (or infinity).

Comment: Isn't it possible to give a formula for $P(T_1=n)$ instead of $P(T_1=2n+1)$ ? Thank you. I make these comments because I am interested by this theory that I do not know. If you can improve you answer, I will be happy.

Comment: Thank you for your remark. I try to figure out why $S_{2n}$ can take only even integers.

Comment: Dear Sangchul, I have understood you comments. I have just one question. In case the random walk is lazy, with $P[X_i=1]=P[X_i=-1]=p$ and $P[X_i=0]=1-2p$, is your proof still valid? In this case, I think we need to add the even terms. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Dingo13, In the case of *lazy random walk*, as you might expect, we no longer have such happy coincidence. So the hitting time now has no obvious restriction on its values.

Comment: $\Bbb{P}(T_1 = \infty) = 0$ isn't it still valid for lazy random walks?

Comment: @Dingo13, It is still true. The question is whether the approach in my answer remains suitable for your lazy random walk. It may not be impossible, but surely we have other ways to deal with this.