# Let $T$ be the hitting time of level 1 in a symmetric simple random walk. Find its mass function $\mathbb{P}\{T=k\}$.

Tags: probability

Let $T$ be the hitting time of level 1 in a symmetric simple random walk. Find its mass function $\mathbb{P}\{T=k\}$ and the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}k^{3/2}\mathbb{P}\{T=k\}$. You may want to use the Binomial Theorem for the root of a sum, and the Stirling formula to take the above limit.

My first approach was to use generating functions, but I ran into a problem. Let the generating of $T$ be $P(s)$. Then
\begin{align*}
P(s)=\mathbb{E}(s^T)&=\frac12\mathbb{E}(s^T|\text{first step is up)}+\frac12\mathbb{E}(s^T|\text{first step is down})\\
&=\frac12s+\frac12\mathbb{E}(s^{2T+1})\\
&=\frac12s+\frac12sP(s)^2.\\
\end{align*}
Rearranging this equation we come to
$$
P(s)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-s^2}}s.
$$
So far so good. But now when it came to trying to derive the probability mass function from this, it required me to find the taylor expansion of this function. This then required me to find the $n$th derivative, which just seemed unfeasibly complicated. So then I was thinking that maybe there was an easier way of using generating functions to do this. Is it possible to solve this question nicely using generating functions, or should I resort to using something like the Catalan number to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: The Catalan number approach seems easier to me: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587549/simple-random-walk-hitting-time-of-1-is-a-s-finite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n$ denote the value of a random walk starting at $k$ after $n$ steps and let $P_k$ denote its law. By symmetry, the required probability equals to $\mathsf{P}_1(T=k)$, where $T:=\inf\{n:S_n=0\}$. Then for $n\ge 0$,
$$
\mathsf{P}_1(T=2n+1)=\frac{1}{2n+1}\mathsf{P}_1(S_{2n+1}=0)=\frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{2n+1}{n}2^{-(2n+1)},
$$
and, similarly, $\mathsf{P}_1(T=2n)=0$. Finally,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{(2n+1)}^{3/2}\mathsf{P}_1(T=2n+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(2n+1)^{1/2}\binom{2n+1}{n}2^{-(2n+1)}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.
$$

---

Usng Stirling's approximation,

\begin{align}
\frac{(2n+1)^{3/2}}{n+1}\frac{2n!}{(n!)^2}2^{-(2n+1)}&\approx \frac{(2n+1)^{3/2}}{n+1}\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}(2n/e)^{2n}}{(\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n)^2}2^{-(2n+1)} \\
&=\frac{(2n+1)^{3/2}}{n+1}\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}2^{-(2n+1)}=\frac{(2n+1)^{3/2}}{2\sqrt{\pi n}(n+1)}\to \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Sorry I'm finding it hard to understand your answer. How do you get $P_1(T=2n+1)=\frac1{2n+1}P(S_{2n+1}=0)$? What does $P$ with no subscript represent? Where does the $\frac1{2n+1}$ come from?

Comment: @WillHarris (1) It should be $\mathsf{P}_1$, of course. (2) Look at [this paper](https://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/monthly753-756-hofstad.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for that useful link! How did you calculate the limit in the last step? I tried using Stirling's approximation, but it didn't seem to be an easy limit to calculate.

Comment: Okay thanks I understand now!