# expected hitting time with a moving boundary

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let $X_i$'s be independent $\text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$ random variables and $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nX_i$$
We define $\tau=\inf\{n\geq 2: S_n>\frac{n+1}{2}\}$.

I want to compute $\mathbb{E}(\tau).$

---

Since $S_n$ is $\text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, I tried to use the Chernoff's bound, that is, $\Pr\left(S_n>\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\leq e^{-\frac{1}{6n}}$ but I wonder if we can compute the exact value of $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$.

After following the feedbacks below, I think that $\mathbb{E}(\tau)\to+\infty$.

Comment: $S_n \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1, n \}$. $(1+n)/2$ falls on the median value. So it shouldn't be hard to determine the probability that $S_n > (1+n)/2$ for all $n$. There are two cases, $n$ even and odd.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I need to compute $$2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k \binom{2k-1}{k}\frac{1}{4^k}.$$ Any suggestions how I can compute this sum?

Comment: $W_{n}=S_{n}-\frac{n}{2}$ is also a random walk with steps $Y_{i}$ being $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. So $E(\tau)=E(\tau')$  where $\tau'=\inf\{n:W_{n}>\frac{1}{2}\}=\inf\{n:W_{n}\geq 1\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W_{n}=S_{n}-\frac{n}{2}$ is also a random walk with steps $Y_{i}$ being $\pm\frac{1}{2}$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. So $E(\tau)=E(\tau')$  where $\tau'=\inf\{n:W_{n}>\frac{1}{2}\}=\inf\{n:W_{n}\geq 1\}$.

This is the same scenario(i.e. the same distribution) for a simple symmetric random walk starting at $0$ to hit $2$ and you're right, the expected hitting time of $1$ starting at $0$ is infinity. There are several ways to prove this and such answers have been elaborated before in this site. [Here's one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587549/simple-random-walk-hitting-time-of-1-is-a-s-finite) for example.

The explicit argument is that for a simple symmetric random walk, if $T_{r}$ denotes the hitting time of state $r$.

Then $T_{2}$ has same distribution as $T_{1}+T_{1}'$ where $T_{1}$ and $T_{1}'$ are iid. (i.e. by Markov property we restart the walk when the state reaches $1$ and that is independent and identically distributed as hitting time of $1$ starting at $0%).

So $E(T_{2})=2E(T_{1})$.

Now, $P(T_{1}=2n+1)=\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ where $\frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ is the nth Catalan Number. This is the same scenario as a Drunkard's walk.

Now you can directly apply Stirling's approximation to see that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2n+1P(T_{1}=2n+1)$ is divergent and hence $E(T_{1})=\infty$. There are other arguments too using Generating functions as elaborated in the answer I linked.

For a more elaborate reference see Grimett and Strizaker Probability and Random Processes, Chapter 5 Generating Functions and applications.